# DbContext ChangeTracker loses Changes in Web request. via Action Filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to create a UnitOfWork Action Filter.

I'm hooking into the OnActionExecuted method where i want to save all changes to the DBContext depending on three rules :-

1. The Context is NOT NULL.
2. The Context ChangeTracker HasChanges
3. No Exceptions have been caught throughout the lifetime of the ActionMethods existence.

Throughout the action methods in the WEB API, I only ever attach entities to the DbContext, its only when the action itself has completed without any errors do I commit changes.

The DbContext in setup using Ninject witha  lifestyle of "InRequestScope".

Here is the UnitOfWork ActionFilterAttribute :-

```
public class UnitOfWorkActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public virtual IActionTransactionHelper ActionTransactionHelper
        {
            get { return WebContainerManager.Get<IActionTransactionHelper>(); }
        }

        public override bool AllowMultiple
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            ActionTransactionHelper.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {

            ActionTransactionHelper.EndTransaction(actionExecutedContext);
            ActionTransactionHelper.CloseSession();
        }
    }
```

In Ninject, the DbContext is configured like this :-

```
container.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

Here is the ActionTransactionHelper Class :-

```
public class ActionTransactionHelper : IActionTransactionHelper
    {

        public bool TransactionHandled { get; private set; }
        public bool SessionClosed { get; private set; }
        public void BeginTransaction()
        {
            var sessionContext = WebContainerManager.Get<MyDbContext>();

            if (sessionContext == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("sessioncontext");
            }

        }

        public async Task EndTransaction(HttpActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            var sessionContext = WebContainerManager.Get<MyDbContext>();

            if (sessionContext != null && sessionContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges() && filterContext.Exception == null)
            {
               var x = await sessionContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            TransactionHandled = true;
        }

        public void CloseSession()
        {

            var sessionContext = WebContainerManager.Get<MyDbContext>();

            if (sessionContext == null) return;
            sessionContext.Dispose();

            SessionClosed = true;
        }
    }
```

I have an Action method that attaches enities to the DBContext like this :-

```
 context.Claims.Add(entity);
```

When the EndTransaction() Method is fired on ActionExecuted, the context object has no record in the ChangeTracker of any changes and the SaveChangesAsync() method is never fired.

However, If i change the Ninject Binding for the DbContext to a Singleton, the code works fine, the change is tracked and the object is saved to the database.

I don't understand why this isn't working per web request?

I dont want to use Singletons in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was resolved by adding the Ninject.WeApi2 Nuget Package.

In the NinjectWebCommon i replaced the NinjectDependencyResolver Implementation with the one referenced in the Ninject.WeApi2

```
**Ninject.Web.WebApi.NinjectDependencyResolver**
```

InRequestScope() now works fine with Action Filters and the DBContext tracks changes.